# Map redirected path in registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry

In my app I want to log actions done in the registry. Some actions are done in `Registry.LocalMachine` and some are done in 32-bit part, with `RegistryKey key32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)`. Right now when I write the registry path to my log file, and that path is redirected, it is not clear what was the "real" path, the one that the user can go to using Registry Editor. The user must know that the path has to have "Wow6432Node" somewhere in there.

How can I deduce the "real" path of the key, even if the key is redirected?

Comment: Expecting your users to dig around in RegEdit seems odd. Even as an experienced user that is very familiar with RegEdit I'd question any program that expected me to use it for anything.

Comment: All this is used for diagnostics. No ordinary user will go to registry editor.